# Shielded breadboard jumper cable wires

Tags: cables, jtag, signal-integrity, shielding, coax

Does it exist a shielded version of 2.54mm pitch breadboard jumper cable wires?
Thin flexible wires, Gauge AWG 24-28. I want use shielded wires for JTAG cable, to reduce electrical noise from affecting the signals, minimize capacitively coupled noise from other electrical sources, the shield act as screening only.

EDIT: I find the suitable cable, from TE Connectivity / Raychem. P/N [55A1114-26-9-9CS2275](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Raychem/55A1114-26-9-9CS2275/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtW9UaYX5J1tPRfPFO%252bggNU78DSnDhhoKI%3D) Unfortunately, it's non-stocked, very difficult to obtain.

Comment: Did you consider making your own?

Comment: Yes, I considered this, but I'm not sure if exist flexible shielded AWG 24-28 cables,  didn't find so far.

Comment: Solid core shielded twisted pair cat 5e or cat 6 wire makes for great shielded jumpers. 8 conductors in a wire.

Comment: Wrap the bunch of wires in some foil, which will act as a shield.  Use a lead with alligator clips to ground the shield.

Comment: Bonus points for the specsheet for that part being made in 1985

Comment: How many conductors do you need in the cable? 10, 20?

Comment: One conductor, shielded. As I noted, I need individual shielded jumper wires.

Comment: If you care about this, you probably shouldn't be using a breadboard to begin with.

Comment: It's not a breadboard whatsoever, I need for custom JTAG cable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use shielded 1.27mm pitch ribbon cable with IDC connectors. Cut off all but the pins on either end of GND/Vcc(optional) side of the IDC (breadboard end of the cable). There will be grounds between each signal conductor, but the ends won't be connected on the breadboard side except for one.

If you can't find short lengths of the shielded cable at a reasonable price (last time I recall several hundred dollars for a small spool), you can wrap copper tape with conductive adhesive around a regular ribbon cable.

This is probably okay for maybe 20MHz with 6" of cable.

Comment: This will be OK for fixed JTAG cable assembly, I want cable consisting of separate shielded wires for handy swapping/interconnecting of individual wires between PC software tools and DSP boards during tests.